# How to publish parallel plugin version streams of an npm package

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm maintaining a library (`MyLib`) published on npm that is a `vuejs` plugin. When I started this library, `vuejs` was at major version `2.x.x`. `vuejs` now has a new major version `3.x.x` that changed how plugins work.

Both `2.x.x` and `3.x.x` versions of `vuejs` are supported and will be for a while longer. I want my plugin library (currently version `5.x.x`) to be available and supported for both.

Options I've seen or considered so far:

1. Have `5.x.x` as the last version that supports `vuejs@2` and `6.x.x` and above for `vuejs@3`.

   - Easy enough
   - Doesn't allow me to release a new version with breaking changes that supports `vuejs@2` *ever* if I follow semver rules.
2. Create a version `6.x.x` of my library that supports both versions of `vuejs`.

   - Potentially possible, depending on the specifics.
   - Makes my library bloated because it needs to support both versions of `vuejs` and have (flaky) runtime version detection to choose the right code path.
3. Publish a separate library (e.g. `MyLib-v2`) that supports `vuejs@3`. Can possibly use a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages), but that would force users of `5.x.x` of my library to change their dependency name with very poor discoverability.

   - Not sure how to manage this in a single repo. [Monorepo](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md)?
   - Clunky, higher overhead

Is there a better way, or at least a not-awful way of managing publishing my library in this seemingly common scenario?

Comment: I will take the first one method, just make sure you declare `vuejs@2` or `vuejs@3` as peer dependencies

Comment: @TonyYip what would you then do if you need to release a new version for `vuejs@2` with breaking changes?

Comment: If it is breaking change and you would like to apply to both `vuejs@2` and `vuejs@3`, then just release v7 and v8. If only on one side, then think twice, as people might expect same API on both version

Answer (score 1):

Use `vue-demi`.  It lets you publish for both vue2 and vue3 in the same project.  When using vue2, you have will access to the composition api as well.

https://github.com/vueuse/vue-demi

From the read me:

> Vue Demi (half in French) is a developing utility
> allows you to write Universal Vue Libraries for Vue 2 & 3

Comment: To anyone attempting this, you can't install `vue-test-utils` v1 and v2 in the same project so testing your plugin will be a challenge. Perhaps a monorepo with separate test projects can work, but I didn't have time to trial that.